# How to grid search LSTM manually using TimeSeriesSplit while preserve/load best_models?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, time-series, lstm, hyperparameters

This is a self-written LSTM tuner class.

```
class ModelTuner_SingleLSTM:
    def __init__(self, params, callbacks):
        self.params = params
        self.callbacks = callbacks
        self.hist = []

    def create_model(self, params):
        # (1) 创建LSTM模型
        model = Sequential()
        # model.add(LSTM(units=params['units'], activation=params['activation'], return_sequences=False,
        model.add(LSTM(units=params['units'], activation='relu', return_sequences=False,
                       input_shape=(params['n_steps'], 37)))
        model.add(Dropout(params['dropout_rate']))
        model.add(Dense(units=1))

        # (2) 编译模型
        model.compile(optimizer=params['optimizer'](learning_rate=params['lr']), loss='mse', metrics=['mse', 'accuracy'])

        return model

    def grid_search(self, X_train, y_train, X_val, y_val, checkpoint_fname):
        X = vstack([X_train, X_val])
        y = vstack([y_train.reshape(-1, 1), y_val.reshape(-1, 1)])

        # 创建TimeSeriesSplit对象
        tscv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=5)

        # 迭代遍历参数组合
        best_score = float('-inf')
        best_params = {}

        for params in ParameterGrid(self.params):
            print("Current parameters:", params)

            # 记录本组参数组合的全部score
            scores_val = []
            i = 1
            # 1. 每一次split迭代 (n_splits==n_fold???)
            for train_index, val_index in tscv.split(X):
                X_train, X_val = X[train_index], X[val_index]
                y_train, y_val = y[train_index], y[val_index]
                print(i)
                print(X_train.shape, X_val.shape)
                print(y_train.shape, y_val.shape)
                # (1) 创建LSTM模型
                model = self.create_model(params)

                # (2) 训练模型
                history = model.fit(X_train, y_train,
                                    batch_size=params['batch_size'],
                                    epochs=params['epochs'],
                                    validation_data=(X_val, y_val),
                                    callbacks=self.callbacks)
                # for key in history.history:
                #     print(key)

                # (4) 加载最佳模型
                model.load_weights(checkpoint_fname)
                # model.save(checkpoint_fname)

                # (5) 在验证集上进行预测
                y_pred_val = model.predict(X_val)

                # (6) 计算性能指标（例如均方误差）
                score_val = mean_squared_error(y_val, y_pred_val)
                scores_val.append(score_val)

            # 2. 计算本组参数下的平均验证集score
            avg_score = np.mean(scores_val)
            print("Average score of current parameters:", avg_score)

            # 3. 更新最优score和最优参数
            if avg_score > best_score:
                best_score = avg_score
                best_params = params

        print(f"Best_score: {best_score}; Best parameters: {best_params}")

        return best_score, best_params
```

But I got an error:

```
ValueError: Cannot assign value to variable ' lstm_10/lstm_cell_10/kernel:0': Shape mismatch.
The variable shape (37, 64), and the assigned value shape (37, 256) are incompatible.
```

It points to "model.load_weights(checkpoint_fname)"

But some epochs are OK with model.load_weights(checkpoint_fname).

the "model" object is just fit and then I load...so why the shape will mismatch?

Comment: Maybe you can try to ask here [https://datascience.stackexchange.com](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/)